# ShootingStrategy cannot be resolved to a type ashot

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, ashot

I'm trying to build and run this https://github.com/Airtnp/CheggDownloader
My environment is eclipse and I'm trying to run this automation to screenshot and download specific area on webpage with ashot with xpath. I'm pasting my error and configuration here.

Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73) on port 14642
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    ShootingStrategy cannot be resolved to a type
    The method viewportNonRetina(Integer, int, int) is undefined for the type ShootingStrategies

```
at ScreenShotDownloader.captureScreen(ScreenShotDownloader.java:73)
at ScreenShotDownloader.downloadBook(ScreenShotDownloader.java:106)
at CheggDownloadRunner.main(CheggDownloadRunner.java:14)
```

Here is my ScreenshotDownloader.java :- https://github.com/Airtnp/CheggDownloader/blob/master/src/main/java/ScreenShotDownloader.java

SiteDetailsProperties.java :- https://pastebin.com/Ecw7beVk

It runs in chrome driver, opens up the website and logs in but doesn't scroll or go to next solution as required.
Any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: so do have you the code/jar for import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.shooting.ShootingStrategy; ?

Comment: I'm sorry but if you can elaborate? where should be code/jar?